# I have a problem with fetching images from an api

Tags: reactjs, api

I tried the same with other api urls and it worked. The image will display and I can work with it. But I often get erros like some "cors policy" and I do not know how to fix this.

```
function Celeb() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

  const handleNext = () => {
    fetch('https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/random')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => 
      setImage(data))
      const unblurit = document.querySelector(".pic img");
      unblurit.classList.remove("unblur");
      unblurit.classList.add("blur");
    }


 return (
    <div className='celeb'>
      <div className='celeb_buttons'>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
      </div>
      <div className='pic'>
        <img src={image}></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

try to habilitate the cors (for more info about it take a look here [mozzilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS))

```
fetch("https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/random", { mode: "cors" })
```

Comment: still get this error:
Access to fetch at 'https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/random' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I think that example is similar to your implementation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples

Answer (score 0):

Add these to request's header

headers: {
Content-Type: "application/json",
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
},

Comment: I got rid of the cors problem by using mode: no-cors. But now I got this error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Have you removed this one?  mode: "cors"

Comment: yes I removed it

Comment: But I still get the same error